# Typing when passing xarray DataArray objects to numpy ufuncs

Tags: numpy, types, dask, mypy, python-xarray

I have a function with type annotations that looks like the following:

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

def compute_relative_azimuth(sat_azi: xr.DataArray, sun_azi: xr.DataArray) -> xr.DataArray:
    abs_diff = np.absolute(sun_azi - sat_azi)
    ssadiff = np.minimum(abs_diff, 360 - abs_diff)
    return ssadiff
```

Which works fine, except for when I check the types with mypy and get:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]]", expected "DataArray")  [return-value]
```

Besides ignoring and casting, is there a way to make mypy understand this? Otherwise, what would the long term solution in xarray or numpy have to be to make this work out of the box?

I found some references here:

- https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/3967
- https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/8199
- https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7370

But I'm not sure I understand all of them.

**Edit**: Just in case there is a question on what `np.minimum` returns at runtime:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import dask.array as da

In [3]: import xarray as xr

In [4]: a = xr.DataArray(da.zeros((5, 5)))

In [5]: b = xr.DataArray(da.zeros((5, 5)))

In [6]: np.minimum(a, b)
Out[6]:
<xarray.DataArray 'zeros_like-fe48a3d33a47c6e3255ffa508dd7dfba' (dim_0: 5,
                                                                 dim_1: 5)>
dask.array<minimum, shape=(5, 5), dtype=float64, chunksize=(5, 5), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0, dim_1
```

Comment: Looks like `np.minimum` returns a numpy array.  I haven't worked enough with `xarray` to know what `minimlum` returns when given an `DataArray`.  Has `typing` been extended to work with `xarray`?

Comment: No, np.minimum dispatches and can return ... anything, depending on what you give it. In the context of the numpy library, it does always give numpy, which is why their own typing passes checks.

Comment: I updated my question with an example just to show that the dispatching works fine and minimum returns a DataArray and preserves the dask array underneath. @mdurant But shouldn't mypy choose the "Any" overload variant of numpy's type annotations and let me do this? Or at least "force" the type with `abs_diff: xr.DataArray = ` or something (this also errors that the assignment is incompatible).

Comment: I don't know where it is defined, but `ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]]` does not allow for Any - it absolutely must be an np.ndarray, whose shape (?) and dtype can be various things.

Comment: It must be falling into https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/eae0b8bc7cebda2c0e32c0552bda21ff64cf990f/numpy/_typing/_ufunc.pyi#L95-L107 which is accepting an ArrayLike and returning an NDArray. The overload below that would probably be what I'd want in this case but it expects input of `_SupportsArrayUFunc` which I'm not sure Xarray is configured to provide in anyway (especially over `ArrayLike`).

Comment: Feel free to open an issue on xarray asking for additional typing, if this is important to you.

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/8388

Comment: As @djhoese has pointed out, the `xarray.DataArray` conforms to both,  `SupportsArrayUFunc` and `SupportsArray`. Now the problem is that numpys `ArrayLike` contains `SupportsArray`, so Mypy will choose the first match, in this case `ArrayLike`. Maybe you could open an issue on numpy asking to change the order of these two overloads (I did not test this, so probably better to file a bugreport with your initial problem).

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/25024